# Displaying fixed width floating point number before decimal

Tags: c, floating-point, avr, floating-point-conversion

I want to display floating point number with fixed width before decimal. So far I managed to do it by taking the integer part, displaying desired width and filling with 0 using "%03d" before number value and then displaying the decimal part.
I want to know if there is standard way of displaying like for example "%3.3f".
I tried the following

```
printf("value: %3.3f", value);
```

But the result was only 1 digit before decimal.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that if `value = 5.34` you want the output `005.340`?

Comment: yes , that is what I want to display.

Comment: This question should be tagged with a language. I was looking for Python - this looks like it might be C!

Comment: It is tagged as "c" although it might be difficult to spot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
printf("%07.3f", value);
```

where `07` means printing at least 7 characters with padding zero.

e.g.

`printf("%07.3f", 3.3);`

prints

`003.300`

Answer (score 2):

You can almost achieve it.  `printf("value: %M.Nf", value);`   will display at *least* `M` total characters and `N` digits after the decimal point.

```
printf("value: %9.3f", -123.4);   --> " -123.400"
printf("value: %9.3f", 12345.0);  --> "12345.000"
printf("value: %9.3f", 123456.0); --> "123456.000"
```

For 3 before and 3 after, use `"%7.3f"`.  Good for values [-99.999 999.999].

Comment: I tried this but I don't know why it did't work.    printf("value: %0M.Nf", value); seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch(), system("pause"), or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("%08.3f", -7.193583);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to avoid code only answers. A little explanation describing how it works and why it solves OP's issue would improve the answer a lot.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of being a strong power consumer, use this format..

```
double offset = 3.14159;
printf("Offset: %06d.%02d sec", (int)offset, (int)(100*(offset - (int)offset)));
```

Comment: The correct answer has already been provided in this 4-year-old question. This answer is full of problems: `(int)offset` is undefined behavior if the conversion overflows, and the multiplication by 100 can round up and produce `100`, displaying a `double` number such as 3.9999999999999996 as “3.100”.